# Unable to launch the receivers in preferred location in spark streaming application

Tags: spark-streaming

I am planning to launch the receivers in preferred location. I have a spark standalone cluster with 10 worker nodes. I would like to launch the 4 receivers in all worker nodes as per my specification. For this I am using the following code in the customer receiver.

```
@Override
public scala.Option<String> preferredLocation(){
    scala.Option<String> test = null;
    if(this.id == 0 || this.id == 1 || this.id == 2){
        test =  scala.Option.apply("abc1");
    }
    else if(this.id == 3 || this.id == 4 || this.id == 5){
        test =  scala.Option.apply("abc2");
    }
    else if(this.id == 6 || this.id == 7 ){
        test =  scala.Option.apply("abc3");
    }else{
        test =  scala.Option.apply("abc4");
    }
    return test;
}
```

above id variables will be set by driver while starting the receivers.
As of now I am hard coded the hostnames. But I have observed that, the receivers are not launched in the specified locations(hosts). Spark version is 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the host name with IP address. Then issue got resolved.